# Best way to implement class selector

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

To clarify: Instead of using enums, where enum tells which method to use, I'm using classes that derrive from the same Base Class. So instead of selecting a method using enum, user will select a class he wants to use (via dropdown interface), and the class contains an override of the method which will be called. After making it work as shown below I tried to look online to see if I'm doing it right. It's a method that solves many problems, but my problem is that I don't know terminology to describe it and to check if it can cause serious problems in the future.

Before I would use Enums to select a tool I want to use (enum tool {brush, eraser, drag}). But to make everything more efficient instead of using Enum I now create a class for each tool that derives trom base class "ToolType". Then I use reflection to find all classes that inherit from ToolType and place them in a static array. And now I'm using this method for most of things in my project, it's easy to add/remove things, no need to edit enum array every time you add a new class. It feels like a best solution to modular project, but I'm yet to find any examples of this, so I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way. What should I be looking for?

```
 static Family ()  {
    List<Type> allTypes = CsharpFuncs.GetAllChildTypesOf<T>();

    family = new T[allTypes.Count];
    names = new string[allTypes.Count];

    Debug.Log("Creating "+typeof(T).ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < allTypes.Count; i++)  {
        Debug.Log("Adding " + allTypes[i].ToString());
        T tmp = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(allTypes[i]);
        family[i] = tmp;
        tmp.index = i;
        names[i] = tmp.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is the constructor of

```
public class Family<T> where T : Family<T>
```

Then I can have

```
public class newToolBase : Family<newToolBase> {
```

}

public class eraser : newToolBase {

}

public class pencil : newToolBase {

}

I'm using Unity and what I mean by "selection" is usually option to manually select something from a dropdown. As you see base class has array of names and they are displayed when user is selecting something. Every spawnable object, every AI method uses this class. I just add a script derived from Base Class which in turn derrived from Family class and it can be selected or added to a list.

From comments below I found out about Dependencies Injection and currently reading about it. I wrote this in hopes that people will immediately recognize what I'm trying to do and point to something like this.

To clarify, there is no obvious problem with my approach but before spending hours on replacing many enums with this I want to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any dependency injection? eg. `Unity`, `MEF`, `Ninject`

Comment: Contraindication: What if you need a second set of ToolTypes? One that you don't want to be selectable, where the first set is ...

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for a [pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns), yet you didn't show what is the problem. Selector? By what? By key - dictionary, by index - collection... Also what is the criteria of why current method is bad? Only doubts? Tell everybody to go into hell, you are the programmer, it's your task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea for what you could do. There are probably better ways of doing this but hopefully I can give you a push in a direction.

`MEF` Stands for Managed Extensibility Framework -

> The Managed Extensibility Framework or MEF is a library for creating lightweight, extensible applications. 
>   [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/)

To get this setup is pretty simple, you need to add the `System.ComponentModel.Composition` library to your project.

I used a console app to demonstrate your use case. First you would have to initialize the MEF container.

```
class MefContainer
{
    public CompositionContainer Container { get; }

    public MefContainer()
    {
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); // You can use an AggregateCatalog if you have more than one assembly.

        Container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        Container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}
```

Now that we have the container class setup, you would need to setup up your tool classes.

```
abstract class ToolType // I've used an abstract class here, but you can use interfaces or normal classes.
{
    public virtual void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

[Export(typeof(ToolType)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)] // Part creation policy is for your lifetime management. NonShared is instanced and Shared would be like a singleton.
class Brush : ToolType
{
    public override void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Brush");
    }
}

[Export(typeof(ToolType)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
class Eraser : ToolType
{
    public override void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Eraser");
    }
}

[Export(typeof(ToolType)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
class  Drag : ToolType
{
    public override void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drag");
    }
}
```

Now it's usage in a console app:

```
class Program
{
    public static List<ToolType> ToolTypes { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mefContainer = new MefContainer();

        ToolTypes = mefContainer.Container.GetExportedValues<ToolType>().ToList();

        ToolTypes.First(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Brush))?.Test();
        ToolTypes.First(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Eraser))?.Test();
        ToolTypes.First(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Drag))?.Test();
    }
}
```

I assume you could extrapolate from the examples above and apply your own own logic.
The above can be just pasted into a console app and should work. Just remember to add the correct references.

This will help create quite a modular app which will help in maintainability and extendability.
There are other Dependency injection alternatives, it all depends on what you require.

Hope this helps.

Extra: To further extend upon this, you would only need to initialise the `MEF` container once for it to be used throughout the project.
I used `ToolTypes = mefContainer.Container.GetExportedValues<ToolType>().ToList();` 
But you could use

```
 [ImportMany(typeof(ToolType))]
 public List<ToolType> ToolTypes { get; set; }
```

or if there is only one

```
 [Import(typeof(ToolType))]
 public ToolType Tool { get; set; }
```